# putting 4 tables into a 2 by 2 grid

Tags: tables

I have 4 tables below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{||c c c||} 
 \hline
 Points & X(m) & t(s)\\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
 \hline
 1 & 2 & 1.48 \\
 \hline
 2 & 4 & 2.76 \\
 \hline
 3 & 6 & 4.02 \\
 \hline
 4 & 8 & 5.22 \\ 
 \hline 
 5 & 10 & 6.43 \\
 \hline
 6 & 12 & 7.76 \\ 
 [1ex] 
 \hline
 \end{tabular}

 \begin{tabular}{||c c c||} 
 \hline
 Points & X(m) & t(s)\\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 0 & 12 & 0\\  
 \hline
 1 & 10 & 1.53 \\
 \hline
 2 & 8 & 2.94\\
 \hline
 3 & 6 & 4.53 \\
 \hline
 4 & 4 & 5.96 \\ 
 \hline 
 5 & 2 & 7.36 \\
 \hline
 6 & 0 & 8.83 \\ 
 [1ex] 
 \hline
 \end{tabular}

 \begin{tabular}{||c c c||} 
 \hline
 Points & X(m) & t(s)\\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
 \hline
 1 & 2 & 1.48 \\
 \hline
 2 & 4 & 2.76 \\
 \hline
 3 & 6 & 4.02 \\
 \hline
 4 & 8 & 5.22 \\ 
 \hline 
 5 & 10 & 6.43 \\
 \hline
 6 & 12 & 7.76 \\ 
 [1ex] 
 \hline
 \end{tabular}

 \begin{tabular}{||c c c||} 
 \hline
 Points & X(m) & t(s)\\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 0 & 12 & 0\\ 
 \hline
 1 & 10 & 1.80 \\
 \hline
 2 & 8 & 3.46 \\
 \hline
 3 & 6 & 4.94 \\
 \hline
 4 & 4 & 6.49 \\ 
 \hline 
 5 & 2 & 8.20 \\
 \hline
 6 & 0 & 9.85 \\ 
 [1ex] 
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I would like to arrange the four tables in a 2 by 2 grid, because right now, the tables take up to much space. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Since you mention tables taking up too much space, couldn't you combine all 4 tables into a single one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty lines between your tables start each table in new line. Delete them between first two and last two tables. For example as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{||c c c||}
 \hline
 Points & X(m) & t(s)\\ [0.5ex]
 \hline\hline
 0 & 0 & 0\\
 \hline
 1 & 2 & 1.48 \\
 \hline
 2 & 4 & 2.76 \\
 \hline
 3 & 6 & 4.02 \\
 \hline
 4 & 8 & 5.22 \\
 \hline
 5 & 10 & 6.43 \\
 \hline
 6 & 12 & 7.76 \\
 [1ex]
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
\hfil   %<---
 \begin{tabular}{||c c c||}
 \hline
 Points & X(m) & t(s)\\ [0.5ex]
 \hline\hline
 0 & 12 & 0\\
 \hline
 1 & 10 & 1.53 \\
 \hline
 2 & 8 & 2.94\\
 \hline
 3 & 6 & 4.53 \\
 \hline
 4 & 4 & 5.96 \\
 \hline
 5 & 2 & 7.36 \\
 \hline
 6 & 0 & 8.83 \\
 [1ex]
 \hline
 \end{tabular}

\medskip
 \begin{tabular}{||c c c||}
 \hline
 Points & X(m) & t(s)\\ [0.5ex]
 \hline\hline
 0 & 0 & 0\\
 \hline
 1 & 2 & 1.48 \\
 \hline
 2 & 4 & 2.76 \\
 \hline
 3 & 6 & 4.02 \\
 \hline
 4 & 8 & 5.22 \\
 \hline
 5 & 10 & 6.43 \\
 \hline
 6 & 12 & 7.76 \\
 [1ex]
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
\hfil   %<---
 \begin{tabular}{||c c c||}
 \hline
 Points & X(m) & t(s)\\ [0.5ex]
 \hline\hline
 0 & 12 & 0\\
 \hline
 1 & 10 & 1.80 \\
 \hline
 2 & 8 & 3.46 \\
 \hline
 3 & 6 & 4.94 \\
 \hline
 4 & 4 & 6.49 \\
 \hline
 5 & 2 & 8.20 \\
 \hline
 6 & 0 & 9.85 \\
 [1ex]
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do you deal with tables that are bigger? I used your code but the tables are pushed down when two tables don't fit the pagewidth.

Comment: @FLonLon, in my answer tables are not in float environment. If you replace `center` with `figure}[ht]`, than tables will in case that on the page is not enough place move to the top of the next page. If you have some special problem, please ask new question.